# Twitter:: External Callback-Not returning User’s Email address

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, twitter-login

I’m implementing external login in Asp.Net Web API application using Asp.Net core 2.0 with C#. While login using Twitter option, the application is redirecting to Twitter login page and after successful login, it is calling application’s callback method. In that method, we’re trying to get logged in user’s email/username but unfortunately, it doesn’t return. Other providers like Google, LinkedIn are returning.

The piece of code which I’m using to get an email address is given below:

```
 var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
 var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
```

[image: Login with Twitter example]
[image: Login with LinkedIn example]